What details are missing in this question?
The question How to create a layout for a quote with image and caption? (closed) has -4 votes and was closed for lacking details. What details are missing?

As a nitpick, the votes can simply be because users found the question "not useful", not necessarily because they thought it "lacked details or clarity". I mention this because asking about the closure may be more productive than asking about votes in general.

Well, this "I don't know how to make it better. Can you help me improve it?" didn't help. We don't "improve" code per se, especially since  your example looks nothing like your desired output. It already has answers (including one of mine) but the downvotes are really because the layout is pretty simple and dozens (if not hundreds) of similar questions already exist on SO, so DV for "Lack of Research". I'd suggest the Cv are because it appears that you have merely dumped some raw code on SO without any real attempt at solving your own issue.

Note that you didn't address the comment you got under the question: ("Can you amend the HTML?"). They are asking you to clarify how flexible are you in the that you want to render HTML. As you later see in one of the answers, which uses completely different HTML code, it was a rather important detail.

@yivi I didn't understand that comment. I asked for clarification but there was no reply

@Paulie_D I actually did tried searching for the answer but failed. That code was the best I could make. I thought that having a MRE was enough to prove that I did the research

Maybe now that you see the answer the comment makes more sense to you?

@yivi after you explain it then the comment makes sense to me then. Does that fully answer your question?

If you want improvement on something that more or less works, then maybe you should consider Code Review instead of Stack Overflow.

It is harder to make CSS questions stack overflow-compatible since you will generally be needing assistance with a visual outcome rather than an actual programming problem for which Stack Overflow is designed. I would certainly add a textual description of the problem rather than relying only on an image which is stored on imgur.

@Gimby I think it's actually easier to make CSS questions SO-compatible given that we have a special feature, Stack Snippets, specifically for HTML and CSS questions (and JavaScript). We don't have runnable sandboxes on-site for Rust, C++, PHP, Python, Go, Java, etc... just HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

@TylerH no that's a tool to make it easier to share an example, but it does not make it easier to prevent a post from becoming a work order and a downvote or even close vote magnet.

@Gimby I don't think the languages being asked about have anything to do with whether a question is viewed as a "work order". Questions about any language can be very good or very bad.

The close reason says "Needs details or clarity" - we bundle these together as the same fundamental problem with a question. I think the problem here has more to do with clarity. But if you mean what I think you do, then the question is also lacking in focus.
Let's look over it step by step:

How to create a layout for a quote with image and caption?

The title implies a work order rather than a proper question. There are arbitrarily many possible "layouts" that place a quote, an image and a caption in various positions relative to each other, with different relative sizes etc. etc. But presumably you are looking for one specific one of those.
This isn't useful to others. Even if others wanted to ask a question that sounds identical, they could have in mind a completely different layout.
An appropriate question about doing a layout with HTML and/or CSS would be about doing the layout, rather than about the overall desired effect. That is, such questions sound like "how do I make an image appear to the right of a text div?".

I want to have this layout:

You should use complete sentences to explain what "this layout" is. What specifically did you find challenging about implementing the layout? What are the interesting features of the layout that need to be implemented in order to meet your requirement?

My try: ... I don't know how to make it better.

Here, you fail to explain: what happens when you try this code, and why is this not good enough? What do you mean by "better" - what should be improved?

Can you help me improve it?

This is inherently not a useful question. We don't offer "help" here. Instead, we tell you how to do specific, well-defined, simple things; and we explain to you why specific, well-defined, simple examples give an unexpected result.
Finally, there is the comment feedback. It is not clear whether you only want the change the CSS so that the HTML will be laid out the way you want, or whether you just want to get this layout (and can change the HTML). You say in the comments that you can change the HTML. But you should instead edit the question - so that we can understand this from the question itself. (In the comment, "amend" means basically the same as "edit", so your answer is yes. It's also helpful to improve your English skills.)

I'm not sure why you got so many downvotes there or on this Meta question (-7 is rather excessive). However, your question was likely downvoted and closed as needing details/clarity because:

you provided an image (which, as it happens, might be blocked [it's blocked for me, at least] due to being on another site) of what you wanted, but no text explanation
your post's actual question, such as one exists, is "how can I make it better", which is about as vague as one could possibly be. Not only is this subjective (what qualifies as better to you?), but it also fails to specify exactly which aspect of the entire post's layout you want to improve.


why is it blocked for you?

@Ooker that image is on Imgur, some organizations choose to block it on their networks for security / compliance reasons.
